# Does the following hold for arbitrary positive integers $a$ and $n$: if $a^n-1$ is divisible by $n$ then so is $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ and $n$ be positive integers. Thanks to the equality
$$a^n-1=(a-1)(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}),$$
all divisors of $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}$ divide also $a^n-1$. The converse does not hold except for a very special case, but maybe always when the number $n$ happens to be a divisor of $a^n-1$ this particular divisor of it will divide also $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^n-1\in\Bbb Z_d[x]$, where $d\mid n$.

The claim $$d\mid a^n-1\Rightarrow d\mid a^{n-1}+\ldots+1$$ is the same as saying that $f(a)=0\Rightarrow (x-a)^2\mid f(x)$. This can be shown by the following derivative-multiplicity test:

> Let $f(x)\in R[x]$ be a polynomial in any polynomial ring over any commutative ring $R$. Then if $f(a)=f'(a)=0$ we have $(x-a)^2\mid f(x)$.

> *Proof*: Suppose that $f(a)=0$, then $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$. Taking the formal derivative we get $$f'(x)=g(x)+(x-a)h(x)$$ If $f'(a)=0$, we get that $g(a)=0$, and so $(x-a)\mid g(x)$, in other words $$(x-a)^2\mid f(x)$$

The derivative is $f'(x)\equiv_d nx^{n-1}\equiv_d 0$, so trivially $f'(a)\equiv_d 0$. Therefore $$(x-a)\mid\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=x^{n-1}+\ldots+x+1$$ and so $$a^{n-1}+\ldots+a+1\equiv_d 0$$ which holds for any $d\mid n$.

Comment: The generalization to divisors _d_ of _n_ is very nice, but a step in the proof needs explanation even in the case of _d=n_. Having proved that  `(x-a)^2` divides `f(x)`, how to conclude that _d_ divides `a^{n-1}+\cdots+a+1`?

Comment: @DimiterSkordev I have updated my answer, remember that the polynomial is in $\Bbb Z_d[x]$, so $\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}\equiv_d 0$ means that $d$ divides the polynomial. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: It seems you regard the following implication as evident in the considered polynomial ring: if  $(x-a)^2$ divides the product $(x-1)(x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)$ then $x-a$ divides $x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1$. I do not think it is evident, and here is a somewhat similar implication that is false in the same ring in the case of $d=4$: if $(x-2)^2$ divides the product $xx$ then $x-2$ divides $x$.

Comment: In  particular case we may have a factor like $a+1$ in $a^n-1$ which may be equal to n. Since $a=-1 $ makes polynomial zero (because number of terms is even)it would mean n also divides it.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout In order to get the generalization for divisors of $n$, it will be sufficient to have a proof of the statement in its initial form. Indeed, suppose such a proof is found, and let $d$ be a divisor of $n$ such that $a^n-1$ is divisible by $d$. Then $n=md$ for some $m$, hence $(a^m)^d-1$ is divisible by $d$, and we may conclude that $d$ is a divisor of $1+a^m+(a^m)^2+\cdots+(a^m)^{d-1}$. It follows from here that $d$ divides $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}$ because $$1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}=(1+a^m+(a^m)^2+\cdots+(a^m)^{d-1})(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{m-1}).$$

Answer (score 0):

For any positive integer $n$, let  $S_n(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}$. Let $A$ be the set of the positive integers $n$ such that $S_n(a)$ is a multiple of $n$ whenever $a$ is a positive integer and $a^n-1$ is a multiple of $n$. We will prove that all positive integers belong to $A$. This will be done by establishing that $A$ has the following properties:

1. $1\in A$.
2. Whenever $n\in A$ and $p$ is a prime number not dividing $n$, $p^kn\in A$ for all non-negative integers $k$.

Property 1 is obvious. To prove property 2, suppose $n\in A$ and $p$ is a prime number not dividing $n$. The statement that $p^0n\in A$ is trivial. Suppose now that $k$ is a non-negative integer such that $p^kn\in A$. We will show that $p^{k+1}n\in A$ too. Let $a$ be any positive integer such that $a^{p^{k+1}n}-1$ is a multiple of $p^{k+1}n$. We will show that $S_{p^{k+1}n}(a)$ is also a multiple of $p^{k+1}n$. Since $p^{k+1}n=pp^kn$, we see that $(a^p)^{p^kn}-1$ is a multiple of $p^{k+1}n$, hence $(a^p)^{p^kn}-1$ is a multiple of $p^kn$, and therefore so is $S_{p^kn}(a^p)$. We will next use the equalities
$$S_{p^{k+1}n}(a)=S_p(a)S_{p^kn}(a^p),$$
$$(a^p)^{p^kn}-1=(a^p-1)S_{p^kn}(a^p),$$
$$a^p-1=(a-1)S_p(a).$$
The needed conclusion can be derived from them in the following way. The validity of the conclusion is obvious from the first equality if $S_{p^kn}(a^p)$ is divisible by $p^{k+1}$. Suppose now that $S_{p^kn}(a^p)$ is not divisible by $p^{k+1}$. Then the second equality shows that $a^p-1$ is divisible by $p$, and this, together with the third one, implies the divisibility of $S_p(a)$ by $p$ because $p$ must divide $a-1$ or $S_p(a)$, but $S_p(a)\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod }p)$ in the case when $p$ divides $a-1$ since
$$1\equiv a\equiv a^2\equiv\cdots\equiv a^{p-1}\ (\textrm{mod }p)$$
in that case. As $S_{p^kn}(a^p)$ is a multiple of $p^kn$, the first equality again yields the conclusion in question.